# iPhone | Core data migration for a new version built from scratch

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I am working on an App update and this version is completely built from scratch and has completely new `coreData` model schema. I need to write `coreData` migration from the older model. I have been looking at resources to write `coreData` migration but all of them need old model file. Since this version is completely new, I don't have the old model schema.

Is there any way I can write the migration such that it dumps the old model when user updates the app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the old App, then you can recreate the model from the compiled model file which is contained in the App bundle:

- Sync the App to iTunes, if necessary.
- Ctrl-Click on the App in iTunes, and use "Show in Finder" to locate the "YourApp.ipa" file.
- Copy "YourApp.ipa" to a temporary directory, and use "unzip YourApp.ipa" on the command line to extract the archive.
- In the extracted "Payload/YourApp.app" folder there should be a "XXX.momd" folder containing a file "XXX.mom" (*XXX* is the name of the model). This is the compiled model file.
- In your Xcode project (or a temporary project), create a new "Data Model" file "XXX.xcdatamodeld".
- Select this file and choose "Editor -> Import ..." from the menu.
- In the import dialog, choose the "XXX.mom" file from above.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I found a workaround. In my appDidFinishLaunching am checking if user is launching this version for the first time I am deleting the old persistent store before creating the new one. So I don't need to do the migration.

Comment: @manish: In this case I would use a different file name for the new store, so you can just delete the old store if it still exists (no check for first launch needed).

Answer (score 0):

Without the old model schema, you cannot do a migration. Well, that's sort of logical.

You only perceivable option is to **reverse engineer** the old model schema and take it from there.

Then you construct your new schema by adding / deleting / changing entities, attributes and relationships.

If you can extract the data from the existing store, just write a custom export function and insert it into your brand new core data store.

Comment: what if I don't have the old schema with me? Even my client doesn't have.

Comment: That is what I assumed. So you have to reverse engineer. If you can extract the data correctly, just build your own import routine and build a brand new core data store.

Answer (score 0):

You can do migration by reading old database with pure sqlite SELECTs and inserting data into new database through coredata model. I've made this in my software to import data from concurrent software :)