# Loading a core data database without having the data model?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, xcdatamodel

Is it possible to load an existing core data database into an app and access it like a normal core data store if I don't have the corresponding .xcdatamodeld file? Is there a possibility to rebuild a fitting .xcdatamodeld from the database? Either per hand or programmatically?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know it that helps, but you can rebuild the .xcdatamodeld file from the compiled model file inside an app (See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13310179/1187415)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the Core Data database file generated by Core Data from the datamodel you don't have, it is a Sqlite database you can open in an [Sqlite database browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). You may be able to inspect it and make queries into it, and possibly recreate a datamodel similar to it, but you will probably have to trick Core Data into thinking it's the same *version* as the original datamodel by copying the information in the version table from a database file created by Core Data with your new datamodel into the old database file.

Comment: I ended up making a new datamodel and repopulating the database. Seems to be the only way.