# Core Data duplicate project for update of a submitted app

Tags: ios, core-data, xcdatamodel

i have submitted an app on the app store that uses core data.
The problem is that i duplicated my project and then lost the first source code. If i update the app using the "duplicated" source code does it delete all core datas users may have stored? i know that if you change the file file-xcdatamodel without mapping the previous datas you will lose all you had stored, can i assume the duplicated project use the exact same file?
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you submitting it to the store as a separate app?

Comment: @Firo no it should be an update of the existing one.

Comment: If you don't have the source code you can restore the Core Data model from the app itself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13310179/1187415, perhaps that helps.

Comment: What 'duplicated' means? Cmd + d over whole project folder on OS X?

Comment: @MartinR i tried that but when i unzip my .ipa i only get a file with no extension that i can't open because the SO says me that it's not supported by my Mac!
EDIT: in the terminal i found the file i got is myApp.app
can i do something about that?

Comment: @RauruFerro Yes exactly that one!

Answer (score 0):

In that case I think that, if you didn't modify your xcdatamodel, the data stored by user will keep during the upgrade. In order to be sure, you can install your own apo from App Store, save some data, update this app from Xcode with your new version and check if the stored data still are there.

If you've modify your xcdatamodel, you must perform a light or a heavy migration, depending on your canges.

Comment: But if i test i it from Xcode doesn't it create another copy of the app due to the provisioning profile i created?